# Maven dependency plugin - download the jar during packaging phase

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want Maven to download and put `jetty-runner.jar` dependency into `myproject/target/dependency` folder.

Part of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.1.1.v20140108</version>
                                    <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

However, when I do `mvn package` from my project directory the `jetty-runner.jar` is not copied to `/target/dependency` folder.

What WORKS however is when I add the following line to `<configuration>`:

```
<id>default-cli</id>
```

and run it with `mvn dependency:copy`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post your full pom.xml, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the maven-dependency-plugin within the `<pluginManagement>` section, maven will do nothing with it. Your `<pluginManagement>` section does only define how the maven-dependency-plugin will be configured in case it is invoked. To actually invoke the plugin during the packaging phase, you need to define the invocation in the `<plugins>` section.

So you can either move the whole plugin configuration from `<pluginManamgement>` to `<plugins>` or you can **additionally** define the maven-dependency-plugin without version and configuration in the `<plugins>` section:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <!-- no need for version or configuration since both are defined in pluginManagement -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

Comment: If the execution should not be inherited to submodules, I suppose it should be declared in the <plugins> section and not in the <pluginsManagement> section.